# Gerund after to be verb

Tags: grammar

I'm trying to understand if this sentence is right, if so, why.

> *The problem is trying to learn without practicing*

I've been looking for the answer to this question in sites and grammars. I didn't find what we use after to be verb, the infinitive or the gerund (ing-form). The grammars don't say anything about this important verb, that's weird.

Comment: How did you use it in the first sentence of your question?

Comment: @Jim I didn't understand your question. My question is why we can use the ing-form after the to be verb in this case: "The problem is _trying_..."